# Module parse failed: Unexpected token in React Project. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I'm a novice at React, so I apologize in advance if this is a very stupid and obvious mistake.

I'm trying to create a Decentralized Application (DApp) for a simple file transfer-over-blockchain.
I'm following the tutorial at : https://itnext.io/build-a-simple-ethereum-interplanetary-file-system-ipfs-react-js-dapp-23ff4914ce4e (tl;dr version - basically a file transfer over the blockchain network. You upload file to IPFS and then send the IPFS location from one blockchain account to another). For the front-end, I am using React.

**Two things to note -**

**1. I am using Ropsten network instead of Rinkeby which has been used in this article**

**2. In REMIX, I have set the environment for deploying as 'Injected Web3'. (something the original project was ambiguous about)**

One of the dependencies for this project is `ipfs-api`, but that is now deprecated. So I had to use `ipfs-http-client` instead. Successfully npm installed it. Upon compiling, however, I get the error

```
./node_modules/ipfs-http-client/src/lib/to-url-search-params.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:61)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * @returns {URLSearchParams}
|  */
| module.exports = ({ arg, searchParams, hashAlg, mtime, mode, ...options } = {}) => {
|   if (searchParams) {
|     options = {
```

The to-url-search-params.js file -

```
'use strict'

const modeToString = require('./mode-to-string')
const { parseMtime } = require('ipfs-unixfs')

/**
 * @param {*} params
 * @returns {URLSearchParams}
 */
module.exports = ({ arg, searchParams, hashAlg, mtime, mode, ...options } = {}) => {
  if (searchParams) {
    options = {
      ...options,
      ...searchParams
    }
  }

  if (hashAlg) {
    options.hash = hashAlg
  }

  if (mtime != null) {
    mtime = parseMtime(mtime)

    options.mtime = mtime.secs
    options.mtimeNsecs = mtime.nsecs
  }

  if (mode != null) {
    options.mode = modeToString(mode)
  }

  if (options.timeout && !isNaN(options.timeout)) {
    // server API expects timeouts as strings
    options.timeout = `${options.timeout}ms`
  }

  if (arg === undefined || arg === null) {
    arg = []
  } else if (!Array.isArray(arg)) {
    arg = [arg]
  }

  const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(options)

  arg.forEach((/** @type {any} */ arg) => urlSearchParams.append('arg', arg))

  return urlSearchParams
}
```

All other files are the exact same as the ones provided in https://github.com/mcchan1/eth-ipfs .

Not sure what the error is... Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This isn't a React issue. This is an issue with your node module.

Comment: And how do I rectify this? Should I post any more code to help in diagnosis of the problem?